# How to fetch data from *.txt file to Iterable<String'> object in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to fetch the data from .txt file and save it in "Iterable<String'> object.
Code below is getting data from file to String, but I don't know how to go from here. I would be glad for any help.

```
Future<String> fetchFileData() async
  {
    String response;
    response =  await rootBundle.loadString('assets/file.txt');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `String` you get from the `loadString()` by new lines, getting a `List<String>` which is an `Iterable`:

```
Future<List<String>> fetchFileData() async {
  String response;
  response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/file.txt');
  return response.split('\n');
}
```

Example call:

```
List<String> list = await fetchFileData();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does, what did you changed and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: Clarifications have been added to the answer!

Comment: Thank you for you help, however I got following error: Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.